# Print the next letter by increasing their ascii code in c#

Tags: c#, string, ascii, console-application

Can i have algorithm how to solve this program?

Write a program in which user gives the string as input and increment every alphabets of string using their ASCII values and print the output in console application C#.

(Like if user enters Abcd it will print Bcde.)

Comment: SO is not a code writing factory, unfortunately.

Comment: just give me some algorithm so that i can code this program.

Comment: should i use string builder to solve this?

Comment: Algorithm: loop through the string, grab the character at index `i`, find its ASCII code, increase it, convert it back, write it to the string.

Comment: See: [How to ask Homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: how to find ASCII code ? I have no idea about it. Would you please explain it by some example? @CompuChip

Comment: please read the question again @KarolisKajėnas

Answer (score 2):

Strings in .NET are sequences of UTF-16 code units. (This also true for Java, JavaScript, HTML, XML, XSL, Windows API, …) The .NET datatype for a string is `String` and the .NET datatype for a UTF-16 code unit is `Char`. In C#, you can use them or their keyword aliases `string` and `char`.

UTF-16 is one of several encodings of the Unicode character set. It encodes each Unicode codepoint in one or two code units. When two code units are used they are called surrogate pairs and in the order high surrogate then low surrogate.

ASCII is a subset of Unicode. The Unicode characters in common with ASCII are exactly U+0000 to U+007F. UTF-16 encodes them each as one code unit: '\u0000' to '\u007F'. The single encoding for the ASCII character set encodes each in one byte: 0x00 to 0x7f.

---

The problem statement refers to "string", "alphabet", "ASCII", "C#" and "console". Each of these has to be understood.

Some people, unfortunately, use "ASCII" to mean "character code". In the context of "C#" "string", character code means either Unicode codepoint or UTF-16 code unit. You could make a simplifying assumption that the input characters do not require UTF-16 surrogate pairs and even that the range is U+0000 to U+007F.

"Alphabet" is both a mathematical and a linguistical term. In mathematics (and computer science), an "alphabet" is a set of token things, often given an ordering.  In linguistics, an "alphabet" is a sequence of basic letters used in the writing system for a particular language. It is often defined by a "language academy" and may or may not include all forms of letters used in the language. For example, the accepted English alphabet does not include letters with any diacritics or accents or ligatures even though they are used in English words. Also, in a writing system, some or all letters can have uppercase, lowercase, title case or other forms. For this problem, with ASCII being mentioned and ASCII containing the Basic Latin letters in uppercase and lowercase, you could define two technical alphabets A-Z and a-z, ordered by their UTF-16 code unit values.

Since you want to increment character code for each character in your alphabet, you have to decide what happens if the result is no longer in your alphabet. Is the result really a character anyway because surely there is a last possible character (or many for the distinct UTF-16 code unit ranges)? You might consider wrapping around to the first character in your alphabet. Z->A, z->a.

The final thing is "console". A console has a setting for character encoding. (Go `chcp` to find out what yours is.) Your program will read from  and write to the console. When you write to it, it uses a font to generate an image of the characters received. If everything lines up, great. If not, you can ask questions about it. Bottom line: When the program reads and writes, the input/output functions do the encoding conversion. So, within your program, for `String` and `Char`, the encoding is UTF-16.

---

Now, a `String` is a sequence of `Char` so you can use several decomposition techniques including `foreach`:

```
foreach (Char c in inputString)
{
    if (Char.IsSurrogate(c)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    if (c > '\u007f') throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    // add your logic to increment c and save or output it
}
```

Comment: That's a very good and complete answer that looks at each aspect of the problem - love it. Although I fear it's a bit wasted on this probably homework-related question. Still, might be very useful for people coming here by accident - so I also want to throw in Joel Spolsky's excellent introduction to Unicode and character sets: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @BernhardKönig Thanks for your feedback. Joel's article is fun but I wonder what would happen if new programmers were taught Unicode BMP UTF-16 first and ASCII only when called out by an IETF RFC that's under study. No modern programming language or operating system uses the ASCII character set itself—not even MS-DOS.

Comment: That's very nice explanation. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One easy and comprehensible way to do it:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcd".ToCharArray());

for (int i = 0; i <= bytes.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    bytes[i]++;
}

Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to transform the string into a character array and then iterate over that array.

For each element in the array, increment the value by one and cast back to character type. (Basically this would work because char and int are the same apart for the char having value limitations according to the ASCII table, and that the computer can relate an image to the char)

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Is it possible without converting into ASCII code?

Comment: converting letters into ASCII code so that increment can be done.